# I've put security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider but it isn't being used during SSL handshake

Tags: java, security, ssl, bouncycastle, java-security

Here is the stack trace of one of the connections in my process:

```
"ServerConnection on port 10000 Thread 27" #521 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000002db4800 nid=0x2d79 runnable [0x00007f0ababb1000] 
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
 - locked <0x00000006d63c51f0> (a java.lang.Object)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
 - locked <0x00000006d6405210> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Message.fetchHeader(Message.java:691)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Message.readHeaderAndPayload(Message.java:709)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Message.read(Message.java:657)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Message.recv(Message.java:1105)
 - locked <0x00000006d6405288> (a java.nio.HeapByteBuffer)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.Message.recv(Message.java:1118)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.BaseCommand.readRequest(BaseCommand.java:869)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.doNormalMsg(ServerConnection.java:723)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.doOneMessage(ServerConnection.java:914)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.ServerConnection.run(ServerConnection.java:1171)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.tier.sockets.AcceptorImpl$1$1.run(AcceptorImpl.java:519)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here I guess instead of sun.security.ssl I should see something used from bouncy castle library.

Comment: Adding bouncy castle security provider will make sure the provider is available for JVM during run time but there is no guarantee that this provider will be used. It is based on the ciphers used in your code. Share the piece of code which makes the SSL connection.

Comment: It's a third party library. But shouldn't that ciphers be searched considering the providers priority?

Comment: It will but what if different provider is specified in the code? If it is a third party, you can look at the third party code (if available).

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly specify a provider from code?

Comment: You can add the provider in the code "Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); " but the suitable provider will be chosen during handshake which is based on the certificates being exchanged. You can specify the provider name when generating the keystore.

Comment: So how "based on the certificates being exchanged" works. Say it encounters a specific cipher to use then it searches that cipher in the providers (considering the priority). But as priority doesn't work in this case then it means that there's somehow explicitly mentioned in the code (which I cannot find) to us JSSE provider

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142797/discussion-between-mdavid-and-loganathan-mohanraj).

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things:

1) Which bouncy castle provider you are adding? Bouncy castle packages the JCE provider and JSSE provider in separate jars and have to use separate provider class. **JSSE provider** class is **org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider** and the JCE provider is org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

2) Yes, the providers are looked up in the order of priority but as mentioned in above responses, which implementation is returned also depends on how the algorithm/protocol is requested in the application code. First a provider should be implementing the algorithm/protocol you are requesting and also it has to register it using the name/alias that you are using while requesting.

For example, if the code is requesting TLS context as javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL"), BC won't return any context as it does not register any implementation with that alias. However, SunJSSE will return a context as it add "SSL" as an alias to "TLS"

Yes, you can explicitly ask the implementation from a specific provider. All JCE/JSSE api has an additional overloaded method that takes provider name. For example,

javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", "BCJSSE");

javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory("PKIX", "BCJSSE");