# Not able to connect to sftp : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail

Tags: java, ftp, jsch

Out FTP server went through migration for some better security (don't know much details about it).

But after upgrade, we are not able to download/upload files from the server. It was working fine before the upgrade. The error log says:

> ns0:ClientCould not connect to FTP Server.http://schemas.cordys.com/ftpconnector/1.1Cordys.FTPConnector.Messages.ftpserverConnectionFailedcom.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.FTPException: Algorithm negotiation fail
>
> at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.CordysSFTPClient.connect(CordysSFTPClient.java:78)
>       at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.FTPCommand.connect(FTPCommand.java:86)
>       at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.FTPTransaction.process(FTPTransaction.java:109)
>       at com.eibus.soap.SOAPTransaction.handleBodyBlock(SOAPTransaction.java:1340)
>       at com.eibus.soap.SOAPTransaction.(SOAPTransaction.java:546)
>       at com.eibus.soap.SOAPTransaction.(SOAPTransaction.java:195)
>       at com.eibus.soap.Processor.onReceive(Processor.java:1024)
>       at com.eibus.soap.Processor.onReceive(Processor.java:997)
>       at com.eibus.connector.nom.Connector.onReceive(Connector.java:483)
>       at com.eibus.transport.NonTransactionalWorkerThreadBody.doWork(NonTransactionalWorkerThreadBody.java:61)
>       at com.eibus.transport.NonTransactionalWorkerThreadBody.run(NonTransactionalWorkerThreadBody.java:26)
>       at com.eibus.util.threadpool.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:67)
>       Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:520)
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:286)
>       at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:150)
>       at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.CordysSFTPClient.connectOnce(CordysSFTPClient.java:124)
>       at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.CordysSFTPClient.connect(CordysSFTPClient.java:64)
>       ... 11 more

jsch jar version used is: jsch-0.1.41.jar
java version used is: 1.7.0_40

Note that

1. We don't own the FTP server and can't change any settings there.
2. Upgrading the Java version is not an option

**Trial 1**
After spending some time on google, I understood that upgrading the jsch jar version might help. So I used the latest jsch jar which is: jsch-0.1.54.jar. After this I started getting following error:

> com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.FTPException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
>           at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.CordysSFTPClient.connect(CordysSFTPClient.java:78)
>           at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.FTPCommand.connect(FTPCommand.java:86)
>           at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.FTPTransaction.process(FTPTransaction.java:109)
>           at com.eibus.soap.SOAPTransaction.handleBodyBlock(SOAPTransaction.java:1340)
>           at com.eibus.soap.SOAPTransaction.(SOAPTransaction.java:546)
>           at com.eibus.soap.SOAPTransaction.(SOAPTransaction.java:195)
>           at com.eibus.soap.Processor.onReceive(Processor.java:1024)
>           at com.eibus.soap.Processor.onReceive(Processor.java:997)
>           at com.eibus.connector.nom.Connector.onReceive(Connector.java:483)
>           at com.eibus.transport.NonTransactionalWorkerThreadBody.doWork(NonTransactionalWorkerThreadBody.java:61)
>           at com.eibus.transport.NonTransactionalWorkerThreadBody.run(NonTransactionalWorkerThreadBody.java:26)
>           at com.eibus.util.threadpool.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:67)
>       Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
>           at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:565)
>           at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
>           at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.CordysSFTPClient.connectOnce(CordysSFTPClient.java:124)
>           at com.eibus.applicationconnector.ftp.CordysSFTPClient.connect(CordysSFTPClient.java:64)
>           ... 11 more

**Trial 2** : Installed unlimited strength jurisdiction policy files (www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html), this was also of no use. Got the same error

Any pointers would be helpful.

Here is the piece of code I am using to connect to ftp:

```
private void connectOnce(FTPConfiguration ftpConfiguration) throws JSchException {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    this.session = jsch.getSession(ftpConfiguration.getUsername(), ftpConfiguration.getServer(), ftpConfiguration.getPort());
    this.session.setPassword(ftpConfiguration.getPassword());

    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    this.session.setConfig(config);

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("Opening SFTP connection to " + ftpConfiguration.getServer());
    }
    this.session.connect();
}
```

Comment: can you set client version to `session.setClientVersion("SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_2.5.3")`? Last time, this helped me to resolve the issue.

Comment: As you have resolved the "Algorithm negotiation fail" (what is actually a duplicate question), remove that part, as it just confuses the question. And update the question title accordingly! + Post [JSch log file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47411185/850848).

Comment: I am thinking i might find some solution with the old jsch jar as well, that's why the subject. 
And with the trial, I Just wanted to provide more info regarding my investigation.

Comment: @Apolozeus: Tried it, didn't work. Same issue

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a solution.

Solution involves modifying the jsch source code. (latest version 1.0.54). I’ve done some research and finally able to force jsch to use “Bouncy Castle” security provider. This involved changing the source code for following classes in the jsch library:

- com.jcraft.jsch.jce.KeyPairGenDSA
- com.jcraft.jsch.jce.KeyPairGenECDSA
- com.jcraft.jsch.jce.KeyPairGenRSA
- com.jcraft.jsch.jce.DH

I've added following argument whenever it was trying to geInstance of the keyGenerator.

```
KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA","BC");
```

got some idea from this post ([I've put security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider but it isn't being used during SSL handshake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634605/ive-put-security-provider-1-org-bouncycastle-jce-provider-bouncycastleprovider))

Comment: Awesome @Amit It worked after fixing one error.  That error was  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711754/why-java-security-nosuchproviderexception-no-such-provider-bc